# scrapy splash css selector not getting data

Tags: javascript, python, web-scraping, scrapy-splash, scrapy-shell

I have this web:

https://analisi.transparenciacatalunya.cat/es/Energia/Certificats-d-efici-ncia-energ-tica-d-edificis/j6ii-t3w2

and am trying to get the total number of rows from the table that is at the end of the web (1.341.412) . the selector is :

```
#app > div > div.container.landing-page-container > section.landing-page-section.dataset-preview > div.table-contents > div > div > div.socrata-visualization-container.loaded > div.socrata-pager > span.pager-label
```

The web loads elements via JS, so I´m trying to get this element via shell like this:

```
scrapy shell "http://localhost:8050/render.html?url="https://analisi.transparenciacatalunya.cat/es/Energia/Certificats-d-efici-ncia-energ-tica-d-edificis/j6ii-t3w2/data/""
```

inside the shell :

```
 fetch('https://analisi.transparenciacatalunya.cat/es/Energia/Certificats-d-efici-ncia-energ-tica-d-edificis/j6ii-t3w2')
```

response status is ok: 200

but I can´t find a way to get the text from `span class=pager-label`

could someone help me please...I can´t find the

```
response.css(' '::text).get()
```

I always get an empty response....

Comment: Did you use `view(response)` in the shell ? For instance, when I do `scrapy shell https://analisi.transparenciacatalunya.cat/es/Energia/Certificats-d-efici-ncia-energ-tica-d-edificis/j6ii-t3w2` when I launch `view(response)` the table you are interested in has trouble to be downloaded `Tenemos problemas para mostrar esta tabla.` maybe due to my python's environment, but I prefer to ask you if you checked by this way at first.

Comment: Yes. That´s not the problem. I used scrapy shell to check, but in the code I´n gettong an empty variable, so it´´s not pointing well the path